# single content type gets added multiple times

Tags: nodes

I have a problem with my drupal site. On some occasion's, when 'author' submits content type, site freezes and this content type gets added multiple times instead of just one time. I don't think that submitting 5 form fields is that heavy for server, that it should cause problems.

Do you have any idea/experiences with this kind of trouble?

Comment: more explanation needed, 
describe your dev enviroment, any modules that may interfere

Comment: It is nothing special. Drupal 7, some form fields and file attachment.

Comment: need more info, some form fields? Do you built content types by a custom module?

Comment: This happened to one of my sites during a DDOS attack from a botnet. My logs were showing PDO exceptions citing 'too many connections'. Have you checked your logs?